# Thermalizing bulk superconductors

Tags: thermodynamics, superconductivity, phonons

I have been discussing with some friends whether or not (or how) bulk superconductors thermalize when placed in an environment far below their transition temperature.

Suppose you have a cube of pure aluminum with $T_c \approx 1.2 K$ and it is placed on the mixing chamber of a dilution fridge whose temperature as read by resistance measurement is 10 mK ($T \approx 0.008 T_c$). Does the aluminum block thermalize? What time scale does it take to thermalize?

My thoughts:

Certainly from black body radiation considerations alone the surfaces of the aluminum should thermalize with the surrounding 10 mK environment. The thing that gets tricky is what happens in the pseudo-bulk fo the metal? I suspect due to the rapid decay of quasiparticles in the superconductor heat transport out of the "hot" middle becomes very slow. i'm not sure how one would quantify this but to me it feels intuitively correct. So, the innards of the bulk could have a temperature much larger than the environment over a "reasonable" timescale and that there are very large temperature gradients between the surface and inner part of the superconductor.

I am not sure of how one would compute the time scale or if there are other physical phenomena going on I am unaware of (surface phonons would enhance thermalization of the inner bulk "surfaces" was one hypothesis suggested to me by someone I know).